# Open a 3rd party app (from unidentified developer) with Applescript or Bash Script

Tags: bash, scripting, terminal, applescript

- I've created an AppleScript that runs a bash script and launches an application
- I've saved the AppleScript as an application
- On my computer, the bash script runs and so does that application; however, on another computer the AppleScript can't open the application because its from an unidentified developer

Is there a way to have the AppleScript open the application even though it's from an unidentified developer?  Oris there a way to open the application with a bash script?

- I know how to open an app inside a bash script, but it runs into the same issue (unidentified developer error)
- I'm not looking to change my system preferences. I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically so any user can run the AppleScript on their machine
- It's OK if the user has to "right-click, open" the final AppleScript to make the Apple Script run, it just needs to open the application that script is opening up without having to "right-click, open" *again*

Here is my AppleScript code:

```
tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
set scriptPath to quoted form of result & "BrewInstall.command"
tell application "Finder" to get POSIX path of ((path to me as text) & "::")
set appPath to result & "OracleInstall.app"
tell application appPath
    activate
end tell

tell application "Terminal"
    activate
    do script scriptPath
end tell
```

Comment: I believe I figured it out. First I switched the "tell blocks". Inside the "tell application 'Terminal'" block, I do a shell script that cd's to the directory where the application is. Then do another shell script that chmod's the application

Answer (score 0):

If you first remove the quarantine attribute, it should work:

do shell script "xattr -d com.apple.quarantine & appPath